# Zip file is created with windows path separator

Tags: java, file, io, zip

I create a zip file using below code. Zip is created properly, then later in my program I try to get a zip entry from this file. And if I print a zip entry name I get windows path separators(Eg `\a\b\c`). But I need this like `a/b/c`. I have not posted reading zip entry code.

```java
public static void zipFolder(File subdirs, String ZipName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

   try (FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(location+File.seperator+ ZipName); 
        ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(fileWriter)) {
            addFolderToZip(subdirs, subdirs, zip);
   }
}

private static void addFileToZip(File rootPath, File srcFile, ZipOutputStream zip) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

   if (srcFile.isDirectory()) {
      addFolderToZip(rootPath, srcFile, zip);
   } else {
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int len;
      try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile)) {
         String name = srcFile.getPath();
         name = name.replace(rootPath.getPath() + File.separator, "");
         zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
         while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    zip.write(buf, 0, len);
         }
      }
   }
}

private static void addFolderToZip(File rootPath, File srcFolder, ZipOutputStream zip) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
   for (File fileName : srcFolder.listFiles()) {
     addFileToZip(rootPath, fileName, zip);
   }
}
```

Comment: May be you should get the absolute file path of the entry instead of file path. It is also good use absolute paths when and wherever necessary.

Comment: can you post screenshot of ZIP file contents

Comment: You can try with zip with any contents, it gives same result

Comment: I am using absolute path only

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting the entry from zip file

Comment: zipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file1); Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
    ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

Answer (score 5):

The root cause of your problem in the following snippet:

```java
  String name = srcFile.getPath();
  name = name.replace(rootPath.getPath() + File.separator, "");
  zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
```

The [File.getPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getPath()) method returns the path with the system-dependent default name-separator.

So, according to [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4244499)

> Within a ZIP file, pathnames use the forward slash / as separator, as required by the [ZIP spec](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) (4.4.17.1). This requires a conversion from or to the local file.separator on systems like Windows. The API (ZipEntry) does not take care of the transformation, and the need for the programmer to deal with it is not documented.

you should rewrite this snippet in the following way:

```java
  String name = srcFile.getPath();
  name = name.replace(rootPath.getPath() + File.separator, "");
  if (File.separatorChar != '/') {
     name = name.replace('\\', '/');
  }
  zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
```